# Regex expression for phone validation

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

So i created my regex expression for phone number format (xx)xxxxxxxx

```
       var patt=(/(\d{2})\d{8}/);
       if(phone.value.match(patt))
      {

      return true;
      }
      else{alert("Enter Telephone Number in (99)99999999 format");
      obj.focus();
      obj.select();}
```

It gives me an error when i put that exact('(99)99999999') format in the textbox. But i realized to get it 10 digits, i had to change the '8' to a '6'. Which i did, my code is working for the format now but i was wondering if anyone knew as to why the 8 wouldn't work for 8 digits but the 6 did.

Comment: Why are you validating the format of a phone number? If I type in (99) 999 99999 (with spaces), does that mean I can't use your site?

Comment: its not a site, its just a homework assignment at uni. I am following the instructions to the word so i dont lose any marks. @HansZ

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to escape the parentheses (because otherwise they create a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)). Second, you need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the regex:

```
var patt = /^\(\d{2}\)\d{8}$/);
```